# Derivations and tangent space

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

First, some notation and definitions.

Let $v=(a^1,\dots,a^n)\in T_p\mathbb{R}^n\cong\mathbb{R}^n$ be a tangent vector and let $f$ be a $C^\infty$ map defined in a neighbourhood of $p.$ The directional derivative of $f$ in $p$ with respect to $v$ is
$$\partial_v f(p)=\sum_{i=1}^n a^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p).$$
Consider $C^\infty_p=\lbrace f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R} | f \text{ is a } C^\infty\text{map defined in a neighbourhood } U \text{ of } p\rbrace$. Then the directional derivative at $p$ is an operator $$\partial_v|_p: C^\infty_p\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
$$f\longmapsto \partial_vf(p)$$
that satisfies the following properties:
$$\partial_v|_p(f+g)=\partial_v|_pf+\partial_v|_pg;$$
$$ \partial_v|_p(constant)=0; $$
$$ \partial_v|_p(fg)=g(p)\partial_v|_pf+f(p)\partial_v|_pg  .$$

Operators $D:C^\infty_p\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy these three properties are called derivations centered at $p$.

Let $Der_p$ be the set of such operators. Notice that $Der_p$ is a vector space.
We have seen that to each vector $v\in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ is associated the derivation $\partial_v|_p=\sum_{i=1}^n a^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}|_p\in Der_p.$
In this way, we obtain a homomorphism between vector spaces
$$T_p\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow Der_p$$
$$v\longmapsto \partial_v|_p$$

Question: how to formally show that the above is a homomorphism?

Comment: Note: your definition of $C^\infty_p$ should be modified by declaring two elements to be equivalent whenever ... holds (fill in the dots). Showing that something is a homomorphism of (real) vector spaces amounts to showing that a map is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map. In other words, you should verify that for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and all $v,w\in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$, it holds that $\alpha v+w\mapsto \alpha\partial_v|_p+\partial_w|_p$.

Comment: @Seurat, your formula defining the derivation in terms of $v$ is linear in the components $a^i$.  What more linearity do you want?